# if substrate features capabilities to proxy votes to the council?

Tags: democracy

recently I developed an extrinsic to proxy the votes accumulated from our on-chain service to referendums with the function VoteSplit in pallet democracy. But I'm wondering if substrate features capabilities to proxy votes to the council? And if it has, we may eager to learn the mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

The [Proxy Pallet](https://docs.rs/pallet-proxy/latest/pallet_proxy/) allows users to set proxy accounts to perform a number of actions on their behalf.

There is a different types of proxies Polkadot offers: Any, Non-transfer, Stakings.... and Governance.
For more information about proxy account check:

- The [Polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies)
- This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tcygkq52tU) that shows how to setup proxy accounts.

This Governance type will allow proxies to make transactions related to governance (i.e., from the Democracy, Council, Treasury, Technical Committee, and Elections pallets).

Check this video about Governance Proxies on Polkadot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5qLFhG4SDw

Comment: The origin question was how to simulate the VoteSplit in Democracy on Council election when a lot of users have deposited their token to a pallet. But you only answers how a single user can delegate its voting right to another party. Not so useful.